# Удалить php код из сообщения

Tags: php, html

Функция `strip_tags()` удаляет все html-теги из текста. Я в принципе не против их использования на своём форуме, но не хочу, чтобы был использован php-код в сообщениях. Можно ли избавиться только от тега `<? ?>` с содержимым?

Comment: Хм, может просто прописать все приемлемые теги во втором аргументе этой функции?..

Comment: у вас что, eval'ятся сообщения на формуе?) lol

Comment: Тсс, я только осваиваю тонкости создания форума/диалога.. Только никому, пусть это останется между нами.=)  
Я же не могу удалить теги, которые создаёт WYSIWYG-редактор, так ведь?

Comment: дык правильный редактор их и не позволит добавить, а преобразует их в &lt/&gt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользовался своей идеей: добавил в strip_tags() все теги, используемыми редактором. Спасибо за отзывчивость.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo preg_replace('#<\?(|php)([\s\S]*)\?>#i', '', file_get_contents('index.php'));
```

Comment: Что делает:  

    [\s\S]*
?

Comment: @ReinRaus данный код выбирает все символы, пробелы и переводы строк. Читайте документацию. Т.е. (.*) не прокатит в силу того, что знак "." не захватывает переводы строк. Такую штуку подметил, разбирая мегатонные регулярки smarty, те еще извращенцы.

Comment: @lampa, так лучше:  

    #<\?(?:php)?.*?\?>#is

Comment: @ReinRaus ах да, про этот модификатор совершенно забыл. Но ваш способ, конечно, не для всех случаев переводов строк подходит. Так-то еще в своё оправдание скажу, что занимаюсь js, а там как раз модификатора "s" и нет :-)

Comment: Не обратил сразу внимание: порядок в альтернативах имеет значение. В этом выражении это не заметно, но вот такое захватит не то, что хотелось бы.  

    preg_replace("/<\?(|php)/", "", "<?php some text");
На выходе `php some text`.  
Конструкция `(expression|)` применяется для гарантированного захвата в сохраняющую группу, даже если ничего не совпало, а (|expression) всегда совпадает с ничем.

Answer (score 0):

А смысл?

PHP код и так не выполнится.

Поле с контентом, которое отправляется на сервер, это строка. И обрабатывается эта  строка, что бы в ней не находилось, именно как строка.